# Lib defects 303 and 396 in std::bitset input/output of stdlibc++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, std, language-lawyer

The input `operator>>` and output `operator<<` of [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) in the [libstdc++ implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset) mention the following defects:

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits, size_t _Nb>
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, bitset<_Nb>& __x) 
{
    /* ... */
    // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS 
    // 303. Bitset input operator underspecified
    /* ... */
}

template <class _CharT, class _Traits, size_t _Nb>
std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const bitset<_Nb>& __x)
{
    /* ... */
    // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
    // 396. what are characters zero and one.
    /* ... */
}
```

Does anyone have a clarification and details on what these defects are? (and how they could be solved?)

Comment: The defect reports can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4485.html).  Just do a find for 303 and 396.

Comment: http://wg21.link/lwg303, http://wg21.link/lwg396.